# Python apply function to a list, store result as a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

Stupid question but I can't make this work for the life of me.

I have a simple function that takes a column value, and returns all rows with that column value. Say it returns all the books by a publisher:

```
def book_publisher(publisher, df):
    books = df.loc[df['publisher_name'] == name]['book_name']
    return [books]
```

Using this function, I'd like to get a list of lists for books by all publishers:

```
[[book1, book2,],[book3, book4]]
```

The end goal is to created a dictionary like so:

```
{publisher1:[list of books], publisher2:[list of books]}
```

I figured I would just use

```
zip(list of publishers, list of books)
```

to get there but cannot figure out how to get a list of books for each publisher.

Comment: You will get more and better answers if you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.  Especially make sure that the input and expected test data are complete (not pseudo-data), and can be easily cut and and paste into an editor to allow testing proposed solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your data frame looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'publisher_name': ['john', 'mark', 'john', 'fred','john'], 'book_name' : ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd','ee']})

  book_name publisher_name
0        aa           john
1        bb           mark
2        cc           john
3        dd           fred
4        ee           john
```

We can get the dictionary using dictionary comprehension:

```
{name: list(book_publisher(name, df)[0].values) for name in df['publisher_name']}
```

If `numpy` array is also acceptable you can drop the `list()`.

I don't know what your data looks like. If it's just a dataframe with `book_name` and `publisher_name` columns, you may also want to change `return [books]` to `return books` in your function, and then you can drop the `[0]` from my answer above.

Comment: This is perfect, thanks for the answer. Didn't even know dictionary comprehensions were a thing.

One question, what does the [0] in your answer do? When I remove it I notice it changes the format of the output but that's the only difference I can see

Comment: When I apply your function `book_publisher` on the DataFrame I created, the list of books is wrapped in an additional list by `[books]` in the return statement. So I access the first (and the only) element of the wrapping list to get the `books` list.

Answer (score 0):

you can use tolist() function instead of [] to convert pandas series to list and don't refers to loc() to get the books

```
def book_publisher(publisher, df):

    books = df[df['publisher_name'] == name]['book_name']

    return books.tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a data frame of 'publisher_name' and 'book_name' columns, you can do it in a one-liner, without using your function:

```
{x: [b for b in df[df.publisher_name == x].book_name] for x in df.publisher_name.unique()}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas `pd.DataFrame.groupby('publisher_name').groups` returns a dict with publishers as keys and row-index objects `pd.Index()` as values.  If you set the DataFrame index to `'book_name'` you get the desired lists of books as values.

Using [Aechlys](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4713386/aechlys)' example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'publisher_name': ['john', 'mark', 'john', 'fred','john'],
                       'book_name' : ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd','ee']})

  book_name publisher_name
0        aa           john
1        bb           mark
2        cc           john
3        dd           fred
4        ee           john
```

you get the dict by:

```
pub = df.set_index('book_name').groupby('publisher_name').groups
```

```
pub['john']

Index(['aa', 'cc', 'ee'], dtype='object', name='book_name')
```

To get the books as a list, simply use Index().tolist() when accessing the dict values:

```
pub['john'].tolist() 

['aa', 'cc', 'ee']
```

or do all in one line:

```
pub = {k : v.tolist() for k,v in 
           df.set_index('book_name').groupby('publisher_name').groups.items() }
```

gives the desired dict with just lists as values

```
pub

{'fred': ['dd'], 'john': ['aa', 'cc', 'ee'], 'mark': ['bb']}
```